# Is there a simple way to highlight a selected node line connection?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am working on a slightly complex node group, and I'm having trouble distinguishing various connections. Is there a way to select and highlight a node connection so it's easy to see where its inputs an outputs are connected?

Here's a quick mockup of what I'd like:

[image: Mockup]

Open to add-ons as well if this isn't doable in vanilla!

Comment: While I don't think it's possible already, although it was proposed, you can make it a bit easier by pressing Shift and dragging over a line to create a Reroute node to make connection out of several parts (if Node Wrangler addon enabled).

Comment: Ahh. thanks for the workaround.